# App crashes when button is pressed that points to table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I've got a button pointing to a view and whenever I see press the button my app crashes. Can anyone tell me why? The code is the implementation file for the view that the button pushes to.

```
@implementation OpenShiftViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    myDictionary = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return 1; 
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myDictionary.count; 
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSArray * allKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    cell.textLabel.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:[allKeys     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell; 
}

@end
```

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: What is the IBAction for the button? What do you mean "pointing to a view"?

Comment: try to load 'myDictionary' inside an init method, because I think the UITableViewDelegate/Datasource methodes are requesting 'myDictionary' before it is initialized correctly.

Comment: The IBAction for the button is (IBAction)openShift:(id)sender;

Comment: The error is Thread 1: breakpoint 9.1

Comment: what is the body of the openShift method?

Comment: I used interface builder so there's nothing in the implementation brackets

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
myDictionary = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];


myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self storingObjectsFromDictionaryToArray];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

```
-(void)storingObjectsFromDictionaryToArray
```

{

```
NSArray *arr = [myDictionary allKeys];


  [myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:[myDictionary valueForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:0]]];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myDictionary valueForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:1]]];
[myMutableArray addObject:str];
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myDictionary valueForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:2]]];
[myMutableArray addObject:str];
 [myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:[myDictionary valueForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:3]]];
 [myMutableArray addObject:[myDictionary valueForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:4]]];
 [myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:[myDictionary valueForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:5]]];
 [myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:[myDictionary valueForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:6]]];
 [myMutableArray addObject:[myDictionary valueForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:7]]];
```

}

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

{

```
return 1;
```

}

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

{

```
return myMutableArray.count;
```

}

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}



 cell.textLabel.text = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;
```

}

Comment: I have done this and it works well so thank you. However, in the table view it loads up lots of letters for countries (e.g. UK) and other garbage. I only want there to be as many rows as there are saved shifts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The error is Thread 1: breakpoint 9.1

Ahm ... you might have a breakpoint activated ?

Comment: How do I deactivate it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting an error -  it is just cause of you having an activated breakpoint.

If you're using Xcode 4, then you can see 'Breakpoints' as seen below. Just click on that to disable breakpoints.

[image]

If you are using Xcode 5, then you have to click this Blue button to disable the breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: I am using xcode 5 and have deactivated the breakpoints but it still crashes

Comment: buddy.. that is an exception.. do u know what '[defaults dictionaryRepresentation]' returns? It returns a dictionary of array. "cell.textLabel.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];"  In this line u must give a string type data to cell.textLabel.text but u r giving an array.. so u r getting dat exception. Below in answer i posted the correct code just have a look in dat

Answer (score 0):

As AlexVogel pointed out in the comments, use init method to initialize the dictionary.
Alternatively, you can use lazy loading using property:

```
- (NSDictionary *)myLoadedDictionary{
    if (!myDictionary) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        myDictionary = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
    }
    return myDictionary;
}
```

Now, in your class, consume [self myLoadedDictionary] instead of myDictionary.

I am not on my machine, but I am pretty much sure that you can define even myDictionary as a getter so that you can use that same name in your code and not myLoadedDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else I would like to point out that should post your error.

Now I also see one problem with cellAtindexPath logic. Your trying to set data on null cell, see [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; will only give you something back if you've already given it something.

You've two options for loading a cell, the new way or the old way, both are kinda of same.

**Option one** and I recommend this one:

in your viewDidLoad (or what not) register a class for a cell identifer:

```
[self.tableview registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

In CellForIndexPath to get the cell go:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The forIndexPath is important here, using old api will return a nil cell.

**Option 2:**

Load a cell and if its nil, create a it.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (!cell) {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

}
```